# When using a window on monitor 1 of 2 monitors, how can I stop the topmost window in monitor 2 from having the "active window" appearance?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

This is a very annoying bug. It regularly fools me into typing in the wrong window, simply because the topmost window in each monitor continues to look as if it's active and has focus (title bar appearanace, and blinking cursor). This really should be taken care of by the operating system--it's managing all the windows, and it knows where my to put my keystrokes, so it should be able to make all other windows turn inactive regardless of which monitor they're on.

End of rant. Does anyone know a workaround? (Other than "get a Mac".)

Comment: I've never seen windows behave like that. Normally there is only one active window, regardless of the number of monitors.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider there is indeed only one *active* window, but the topmost window in both monitors has the active window *appearance* (title bar colour etc) so that it looks as though your typing will go there. (If you click the title bar of different windows, you'll see what I mean, it gets darker for the active window.) If you don't see the same problem, what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I've been using multiple monitors since Windows 95 and I've never seen what you describe, up to Windows 8.1. You could try holding Shift after login, to prevent autostart. Programs I could imagine being responsible: Tools that modify window behavior, skins or even graphics drivers.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible you've just never noticed it as a problem? I've seen people complaining about it here and there, but couldn't find any solutions (other than the "get a Mac" cited in my question) so thought I'd see if anyone on SU could help.